# custom lightning datatable inline editing : data cleared when changing picklist value

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am working on a custom lwc datatable, in order to add a picklist column, as the picklist is not a type for datatable column. the result is bellow.
[image: datatable with inline insert]

The last line of the table is added to the table when we click "Add", so the user will populate the values of the the record.
The  difficulty here is :
When changing picklist value, the bottom bar of inline editing doesn't appear automatically,
[image]

the work around that I found is to edit draftValues variable :

```
this.draftValues = [...this.data];
```

This solution unfortunately clear other columns values.

Thanks.